# Spring Data JPA and Exists query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I'm using Spring Data JPA (with Hibernate as my JPA provider) and want to define an `exists` method with a HQL query attached:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {

  @Query("select count(e) from MyEntity e where ...")
  public boolean existsIfBlaBla(@Param("id") String id);

}
```

When I run this query, I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean`.

How does the HQL query have to look like to make this work? I know I could simply return a Long value and afterwards check in my Java code if `count > 0`, but that workaround shouldn't be necessary, right?

Comment: obviously you could change your JPQL query to return a boolean ... by not returning "count(e)" and instead returning a boolean expression

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I think you can simply change the query to return boolean as

```
@Query("select count(e)>0 from MyEntity e where ...")
```

PS:
If you are checking exists based on Primary key value `CrudRepository` already have `exists(id)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `exists(id)`, but my where clause contains some complex constraints...

Comment: `count(e)>e` will likely only work with certain databases (e.g. Oracle). With DB2 it does not and you will have to use `select case when count(e) > 0 then true else false end from Entity e`

Comment: do a SQL exists query here instead of count rows.  Using count has to complete all rows in an index (hopefully) or else with no index a table scan.  SQL exists will return after the first encountered row rather than find every row and count them the way count(*) does.  In a 10 row table this is no issue in 10s/100s of thousands and beyond this matters.

Comment: Basically, checking counting something is slower than simply checking for it's existance; in the absence of better solutions, the answer works, but it is suboptimal.

Comment: I don't know if anybody pointed to this, for all things Hibernate I look at Vlad Mihalcea's work. I just solved this same problem with this link.
https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-exists-query/
In my cases, I was able to leverage JPARepository.existsById().

Comment: @JRA_TLL Doesn't work with Oracle. 30 upvotes = maybe it did? Not anymore ...

Answer (score 226):

*Spring Data JPA 1.11* now supports the `exists` projection in repository query derivation.

See documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-11-0).

In your case the following will work:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {  
    boolean existsByFoo(String foo);
}
```

Comment: If you'll add a working example I'll be happy to upvote.

Comment: @StefanHaberl I have included one example.

Comment: That's the whole point of Spring data - you don't have to write any HQL :)

Comment: @bartektartanus I disagree. Automatic query creation works for simple use cases only. If you have complex business logic and want to push that into your query (rather than filter in Java in-memory), there's no way around a nice JPA/HQL query.

Comment: Yup, but if you want to check if there is a record with value on one field - this is definitely simple use case :) But for more complex, I agree - spring data is sometimes not efficient.

Comment: Doesn't work. `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property existsByXxx  found for type Xxx!`

Comment: @Jagger, could you please provide a sample code, and also could you check if spring-data-jpa's version is 1.11 or higher?

Comment: @AnkitSoni The JPA version must be all right, because it is coming from Spring Boot version 1.4.6. I have already reopened the [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-851) in Spring Jira. There you can see also the sample code.

Comment: @AnkitSoni It turned out, the Spring Data JPA 1.11 is first available in Spring Boot 1.5.

Comment: This is great and easy. Works in Spring Boot 2.0.4  `boolean existsByUsername(String username);`

Comment: Initially it was not working for one of the property named tank_no. I was trying to use the method boolean existsByTank_no(String tank_no); Reason was an underscore is not supported as it is reserved character. When I changed property name to tankNo and method name to existsByTankNo(String tankNo); it is working now.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the correct approach. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 25):

in my case it didn't work like following

```
@Query("select count(e)>0 from MyEntity e where ...")
```

You can return it as boolean value with following

```
@Query(value = "SELECT CASE  WHEN count(pl)> 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM PostboxLabel pl ...")
```

Answer (score 22):

It's gotten a lot easier these days!

```
@Repository
public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, UUID> {

    Boolean existsByName(String name); //Checks if there are any records by name
    Boolean existsBy(); // Checks if there are any records whatsoever

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Since Spring data 1.12 you can use the query by Example functionnality by extending the `QueryByExampleExecutor` interface (The `JpaRepository`already extends it).
Then you can use this query (among others) :

```
<S extends T> boolean exists(Example<S> example);
```

Consider an entity `MyEntity` which as a property `name`, you want to know if an entity with that name exists, ignoring case, then the call to this method can look like this :

```
//The ExampleMatcher is immutable and can be static I think
ExampleMatcher NAME_MATCHER = ExampleMatcher.matching()
            .withMatcher("name", GenericPropertyMatchers.ignoreCase());
Example<MyEntity> example = Example.<MyEntity>of(new MyEntity("example name"), NAME_MATCHER);
boolean exists = myEntityRepository.exists(example);
```

Comment: Not really relevant in  my case since my query is in HQL

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the accepted answer, I'm suggesting another alternative.
Use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/), create a predicate and use the `exists()` method that accepts a predicate and returns Boolean.

One advantage with QueryDSL is you can use the predicate for complicated where clauses.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Case` expression for returning a `boolean` in your select query like below.

```
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN count(e) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM MyEntity e where e.my_column = ?1")
```

Comment: which ones? afaik it will always return boolean, no?

Comment: Which all databases did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Spring data provides method for checking the existence of a row using field:
example: boolean existsByEmployeeIdAndEmployeeName(String employeeId, String employeeName);

Answer (score -7):

You can use .exists (return boolean) in jpaRepository.

```
if(commercialRuleMsisdnRepo.exists(commercialRuleMsisdn.getRuleId())!=true){

        jsRespon.setStatusDescription("SUCCESS ADD TO DB");
    }else{
        jsRespon.setStatusCode("ID already exists is database");
    }
```