# How to find first in JPQL

Tags: java, database, jpa, jpql

I have a query to find if a value already exists within the database. I am using it to validate a resource before it is inserted onto the database.
it looks like this:

```
  @NamedQuery(name = "findByName", query = "SELECT g FROM Group g where g.value= :value")
```

and on the data access the implementation is as follows:

```
final TypedQuery<Group> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findByName", Group.class);
    query.setParameter("value", value);
    return !query.getResultList().isEmpty();
```

It does work and does the job, however I think that  query.getResultList().isEmpty() is not the right syntax that I need plus I was looking to make it faster and return once the value is found rather than looping through every row on the database.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about count? **[Spring Data JPA and Exists query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392129/spring-data-jpa-and-exists-query)**

Comment: Have you thought about COUNT? **[Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392129/spring-data-jpa-and-exists-query?answertab=active#tab-top)**

Comment: unfortunately Spring is not an option as we went the other way. Now doing a COUNT definitely improves it a bit. However I am still not sure about query.getResultList() for this query. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "existsByName", query = "SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(g) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM Group g where g.value= :value")

boolean exists = entityManager.createNamedQuery("existsByName",Boolean.class).setParameter("value",value).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Interesting, that looks very clean as well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Use the `COUNT` function:

  ```
  @NamedQuery(name = "findByName", query = "SELECT COUNT(g) FROM Group g where g.value= :value")
  ```

  This removes the penalty for creating the actual entities (plus eager loading, etc.)
- Use `TypedQuery.setMaxResults()` to set the maximum number of results retrieved to 1.

  ```
  query.setMaxResults(1);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at using [pagination](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jpa-correctly-to-avoid-complaints-of-a-slow-application/) to improve the speed.

`query.setMaxResults(1).getResultList()` 
or 
`setFirstResult()`