# How to use projection with Query by Example in Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, projection, query-by-example

I'm trying to filter data using [query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example). It's working for entities and [primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39931973/1452089), but not for [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). Do You know if such functionality available in Spring Data Jpa?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment it's not implemented in Spring Data Jpa [2.1.0.RC2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.RC2/reference/html/), but as workaround it's possible to use extension like [specification-with-projection](https://github.com/pramoth/specification-with-projection)