# Jpa Spring Boot error -> cannot convert object to type boolean

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Hello the actual error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 

Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [boolean] for value '{2, ramesh, pass, 12345, ramu}'; 

nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [boolean]
```

Here i tried to create a method to find users by id , but when i tried to put the values into boolean type it gives above error

```
@Query("select case when count(s)>0 then true else false end from user_dao s where s.id =:id ")

@Query(value = "select * from user_dao where id =:id ", nativeQuery = true)
boolean isStudentExistsById(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

in `main` method -> this should print true or false.

```
System.out.println(userRepo.isStudentExistsById(2));
```

in constructor of bean

```
    UserDao(int id, String name, String phone, String user_name, String 
    password) {
        
        
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Comment: error is for Sysout line

Comment: Your request `select * from user_dao where id =:id` have a `user` for response, not a `boolean`, you must adapt you request to make it select a `boolean`.

Comment: the query's response is a entity and you indicate is a boolean, you need change boolean to entity(your dao), or change your query to return a boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way - use method of `CrudRepository` (your repository inherited it usually):

`boolean existsById(Integer id)`

For other options see [Spring Data JPA and Exists query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392129/spring-data-jpa-and-exists-query)

Comment: yes ty actually i changed the code that our teacher gave us where he had actually passed a query which would return a boolean value , i will now try using existsById method cause he never explored on that